# scan values of certain class elements on page load and run a function to several elements with certain values only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, if-statement

I am trying to make an image censor function on page load.

1. scan values of certain class elements on page load
2. if several elements' value goes over 5
3. change img src for ones value count more than 5

I think I get how to scan and change after reading other questions in stackoverflow but I cannot change only specific ones.

from my understanding, below code will censor all images when scan a single 6

for example:
HTML

```
<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="naked_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">6</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var count = $('.report-count').val();
   if (count > 5 ) { 
     $('.showing-image').attr('src', 'censored.jgp');
   }
});
```

Please help

Comment: You could use an [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, if you insist on jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, my knowledge is short and tried vanowm's answer and problem got solved. I will look into this .each loop too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` for that:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.report-count')
    .filter((i, node) => +node.textContent > 5)
    .prev()
    .attr("src", 'censored.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="naked_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">6</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>
```

And same thing but with vanilla javascript (aka faster):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e =>
{
  const report = document.querySelectorAll(".report-count");
  for(let i = 0; i < report.length; i++)
  {
    if (+report[i].textContent > 5)
    {
      report[i].previousSibling.src = 'censored.jpg';
 /* use this line instead if img and p.report-count are not next to each other, but they have common parent */
      //report[i].parentNode.querySelector("img.showing-image").src = 'censored.jgp';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="naked_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">6</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>
```

In case `img` and `.report-count` are not siblings:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
{
  const box = document.querySelectorAll(".auto-listed-box");
  for(let i = 0; i < box.length; i++)
  {
    if (+box[i].querySelector(".report-count").textContent > 5)
    {
      box[i].querySelector("img.showing-image").src = 'censored.jpg';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="naked_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">6</p>
</div>

<div class="auto-listed-box">
<img class="showing-image" src="normal_image.jpg"><p class="report-count">0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are these multiple `<p>` tags  have the same class? if not, than this should work fine. However, if `.report-count` element is not next to the image, you'll need use something like this instead (assuming both `p` and `img` elements have common parent):
`report[i].parentNode.querySelector("img.showing-image").src = 'censored.jgp';` (and the question is gone...)

Comment: sorry for deleting the comment question, I wanted to try more before ask more but you were too fast.
deleted question: Thank you but I have multiple p tags and how do I change code?

Comment: img tag and p tag are far apart descendant and ancestors, is there any way to make this work without making thme parent and child?

Comment: I use Pycharm and the error console says "e" is unused parameter, is this ignorable?

Comment: I've added third variant. "e" error is ignorable.

Comment: WORKS SO WELL!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH vanowm the great.

Comment: I want to use this same code in different pages but 
1) .textContent  after +box[i].querySelector(".report-count")  making errors and doesn't work on different page.
2) when I try to manipulate this code to make another function putting .src after +box[i].querySelector(".report-count") it makes errors too.
The original one work fine. Do you have any idea why these errors happen?

Comment: If another page has the same basic structure, than I don't know without seeing it.

Comment: another page has pretty much has same structure but only 1 specific array compared to the original question page that has multiple array that you advised with for loop with box[i]. (the original page = list of posts, different page = detail page of 1 post) so I am trying to find out if then method without for loop. Am I on a right track?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you are trying to do...as long as both `.report-count` and img are inside `.auto-listed-box` it should work just fine...

Comment: Thank you, I used simple javascript if else statement to make this work, since there is only 1 array!